# Trying to delete several directories in Ubuntu 22.04, -r option in rmdir is not allowed

Tags: delete

Trying to delete some directories for removed software in 22.04 and when I open Term and type in 'sudo rm -r *directory name* it comes back with this error message:

rmdir: invalid option -- 'r'

This -r option is not new and is shown all over the internet as the proper option to use to delete the dir and all it's files so why doesn't it work in 22.04 now? Even when I force the '22.04' in a google search, the articles that pop up still show the -r option as working in 22.04. I haven't found a sub for the -r.

What do I use instead to delete entire directories with files inside? Or what's the proper way to del dirs? Thanks.

Comment: `rm` or `rmdir` ? `rmdir` has no option "-r"

Comment: If you want to recursively delete directories, use `rm` (not `rmdir`) but with the `-r` option.  Also use `-f` if you want to force it without asking you.

Comment: Thanks, all, found the method. Making it too hard again, I was.

Comment: As you know this is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer as an edit inside the question. You may answer your own question by clicking on the button below or accept another answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

`rmdir` is for removing empty directories and already implies it is a directory. The `-r` is for `rm`. `rm` removes files and the `-r` is for recursive (meaning also directories; empty or with files)

Manual for [rmdir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rmdir.1.html):

```
 Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), if they are empty.

   --ignore-fail-on-non-empty

          ignore each failure that is solely because a directory

          is non-empty

   -p, --parents
          remove DIRECTORY and its ancestors; e.g., 'rmdir -p a/b/c'
          is similar to 'rmdir a/b/c a/b a'

   -v, --verbose
          output a diagnostic for every directory processed

   --help display this help and exit

   --version
          output version information and exit
```